# Put an item in Startup folder without admin rights

Tags: windows-7, boot, administrator, windows-pe

I need to put a script in windows 7 (Enterprise) at startup after the login, but I don't have the admin rights. We need to put it for all users who use this computer.

I share a computer at work with a few more people. If I can put in the this script in startup, it is really going to help all of us. The company is very big and hence there is a lot of red tape involved if I asked the IT department to do it for us.

I have already ascertained that I can't even boot up with a USB or a CD. So, booting up with some Windows PE operating system is also out of the question.

Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: This cannot be done without administrator privileges.

Comment: :( really? There has t o be way!

Comment: Yes;  Really;  You really do need Administrator permissions to do this.

Comment: I mean, it is windows... aren't there any open loop holes?

Comment: **No** What you want requires Administrator permissions.  Since you cannot change what programs start up when a user logs in.  Why don't you just create a shortcut that is started manually by the user instead?

Answer (score 2):

No with the details provided it's not possible.

If you are able to change boot order, you could boot of a USB/CD containing a operating system and manually place script in start folder for all users.
You could also use offline registry editor if booting off a CD/USB.

If you cannot change boot order then the only other option would be to exploit a process running as administrator on the computer. Unless you can write you own shellcode and have an understanding of exploits I would stay away from that area. As exploits are not always what they claim to be you never know what shellcode that exploit might run on your system.